# Convert Object C to Swift fetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, converters

I have code in Objective-C

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Doctor"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id != nil"]];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES]];
```

and try convert to Swift

```
var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Doctor")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id != nil")
let disctanceSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"distance",ascending: true)
let lastNameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"lastname",ascending: true)
 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key:"distance",ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key:"lastname",ascending: true)
```

How convert Objective-C to Swift

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: I don;t know how convert fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES]]; this code on Swift

Comment: Sorry, I still did not get your problem!

Comment: `@[object1, object2]` corresponds to a `NSArray`, with `object1` and `object2` in Objective-C (Short Hand Syntax). I think that was the part you didn't understand. Now, you may know, or at least find ho to make an array in Swift to fix your issue.

Comment: There is a fancy [Online-Converter](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/)

Comment: @vadian I use this convert sometimes don't corrert covert

Comment: In this case it does convert correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need is this

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastname", ascending:true),NSSortDescriptor(key: "distance", ascending: true)]
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: and how ascribe to  fetchRequest ?

Comment: my answer was reedited, check if this do what you need

Comment: now i try ascribe to fetchRequest to sortDescriptors  show error fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]

Comment: you maybe have to put fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors instead of  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]